# Why can't I do list click event in simulator in action on google

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I was making a list example and testing the screen change on click. But what does this mean it doesn't work in the simulator?

Is it because the test Simulator is bad?



[Basic list example]

```
conv.session.typeOverrides = [{
    name: 'prompt_option',
    mode: 'TYPE_REPLACE',
    synonym: {
      entries: [
        {
          name: 'ITEM_1',
          synonyms: ['Item 1', 'First item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #1',
             description: 'Description of Item #1',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_2',
          synonyms: ['Item 2', 'Second item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #2',
             description: 'Description of Item #2',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_3',
          synonyms: ['Item 3', 'Third item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #3',
             description: 'Description of Item #3',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_4',
          synonyms: ['Item 4', 'Fourth item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #4',
             description: 'Description of Item #4',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        ]
    }
  }];

  // Define prompt content using keys
  conv.add(new List({
    title: 'List title',
    subtitle: 'List subtitle',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'ITEM_1'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_2'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_3'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_4'
      }
    ],
  }));
```

[Click on the first item#1]

[image]



[ERROR]
[image]

Please tell me why it is not possible in the simulator and if there is an example for testing by linking to a mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states and as in this other case where the error is seems - accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984172/google-actions-simulator-does-not-work-for-standard-google-assistant-features) - indeed, this seems to be due to the fact that the simulator doesn't have all the same features that the normal Assistant has and this case cause errors or even misleading messages. You can get more details on how to test in a device, by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator#on_device_testing).

However, in addition to that, you can give it a try checking the permissions of your test account - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516281/12767257) - due to the fact that sometimes it might be an issue there. Just go to the [Activity Controls](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols) of your account and confirm that: Web & App Activity; Device Information and Voice & Audio Activity are enabled for it. In case it's not this, it's indeed, a lack of feature of the simulator.